# No Error but why we don't get input for second scanf() statement

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{ 
    char ch;
    int i;
    scanf("%c", &i);/* i know this must be reversed for next input but I want to know the impact of this code if we use scanf type char for integer data type*/
    scanf("%d", &ch);
    printf("%c %d", ch, i);
    return 0;
}
```

No Error but  why don't get input for second scanf() statement

Comment: Using incorrect format specifiers is an undefined behavior.

Comment: Look at the order of your input parameters and the variables you're populating therein. A *debugger* would have shown you after your first `scanf` with `%c` that `ch` does not contain what you just typed, and leading you to investigate why.

Comment: please post the actual input so we know what the program is seeing on stdin.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the posted code causes the compiler to output a long long list of warnings and errors, When compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  amongst other things, my compiler is saying there are a lot of `\315` and `\276` characters in the program.   Please re-enter the program without the invalid characters.

Comment: user3629249 thanks you I got it.

Answer (score 1):

You declared `i` to be an `int` and `ch` to be a `char`

In your `scanf` you have `%c` for `i` and `%d` for `ch` while `%c` is for `char`s and `%d` for `int`s.

So just turn them around and you'll be fine.

With `printf` you have the correct format.

Comment: If you surround your inline code with backticks `'\`'` your code (e.g. `%c`) will stand out and be in monospace type.

Comment: ah didnt know that, thanks